# Uniform convergence and relative error?

Tags: convergence-divergence, approximation, uniform-convergence

I never took a class where uniform convergence was introduced, so I only know the Definition and not much more about it.

I have an Approximation of some sequence of functions $f_n$ by some function $g$. 
I know that if we introduce $\varepsilon(x)$ as the relative error, thus 
 $f_n(x)= g(x)\left(1+\varepsilon_n(x)\right)$, 
that $\varepsilon_n(x) < \varepsilon_n(y)$ for $x >y$, thus the error decreases with increasing function Argument. We further know that $\varepsilon_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ for every fixed $x=O(1)$.

Is this enough to show that the convergence of $f$ to $g$ is uniform in $x$?

Comment: Uniform convergence is (in most cases) about a *sequence* of functions. For example, a sequence of functions $f_n$ might converge to $g$. But $f$ by itself is just one function. It doesn't make sense to ask whether it converges uniformly to $g$.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I am sorry about that. $f(x)$ is a sequence, thus $f_n(x)$. 
For example: 
Consider $f_n(x):= Pr[Bin(n,p)=x]$ for some $p=p(n)$. For $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: A sequence of functions can converge to *a* function, not to a sequence of functions.

Comment: I am sorry for again making a mistake. It seems to be too early. :-)

Comment: I don't think the "More details section" is a clear statement of your problem. In particular, when you use $\sim$, I presume this is for equivalence of functions, but it's not clear whether this is for $n \to +\infty$, for $x \to 7$, etc.

Comment: Thank for the hint that is not clear enough. I tried to clarify it. I use the Definition that $f \sim g$ means that $\lim \frac{f}{g} = 1$

Comment: Yes, but the limit of $f/g$ as what approaches what?

Comment: as $n$ approaches $\infty$ we have for each fixed $x$ that $f_n(x)$ approaches $g(x)$ with an error that goes to $0$. I am not sure whether this answers your question. Sorry if I am a Little bit complicated. But I am really a beginner in this Topic, and it's quite hard to me. I tried to clarify it in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: This only answers the first version of the question.

To answer your question, on $(0,+\infty)$, let $f_n(x) = x + \frac{1}{n}\sqrt{x}$, and $g(x) = x$. Then the relative error $1/n\sqrt{x}$ decreases with $x$ and tends to zero for any fixed $x$. However, the absolute error is $\sqrt{x}/n$, which is unbounded for all $n$. Thus $f_n$ cannot converge uniformly to $g$.

Comment: thank you for this result! I see that uniform convergence seems not to be what I am looking for. I am not at all interested in the aboslute error, only in the relative error. 
What I really would like to show is the clarified Statement in the "more Details" section. This does not Need to say anything about uniform convergence. I only would like to add These Errors, but I do not know what I Need for this. 
Someone told me that it might be enough to have monotonically decreasing Errors. Is this true? Would be very grateful if you could help me, as you seem to know what you're talking about. :-)

Comment: Well, if you're interested in the relative error, then you might want to know whether $\log f_n$ converges to $\log g$. In that case, your hypothesis does guarantee uniform convergence if you consider your functions to be defined on an interval that includes its left endpoint, such as $[0,+\infty)$. However, this isn't the case for $(0,+\infty)$. I'm not sure about the second part of your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do I really Need to show this in order to show that $h_n(x+t)-h_n(x)=t g(x+1) (1+o(1))$?
All I want to show is that 
$$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{h_n(x+t)-h_n(x)}{t g(x+1)}.$$
So, as I am very very confused at this Point (I thought this would trivially follow from the assumptions, but it seems not to), I would be really grateful if you could help me with the concrete example. I will post it in the original question!!

Comment: I'm sorry, but at this point I don't have any thoughts on the second part of your question. I have a bit of trouble following what's being asked, and I'm uncertain whether I'd be able to answer.

Comment: I can understand this. It might look very strange. 
What I tried to post is that $h_n(x)$ can be approximated by $g(x)$. I provided the relative Errors in both directions. So, now I would like to show that if we have not only $h_n(x+1)-h_n(x)$ but $h_n(x+t)-h_n(x)$ that we then can simply multiply the error by $t$.

Comment: Maybe you should post this part as a separate question. That way it will be clear to people that it hasn't received an answer.

Comment: So. This was the concrete example with all formulas. If you do not want to look at it, I can understand this. 
The other possibility is: Could you tell me what I exactly need to show for $\varepsilon_n(x)$ for $h_n(x+1)-h_n(x)=g(x)\left(1+\varepsilon_n(x)\right)$ in order to show that 
$h_n(x+t)-h_n(x)=t g(x) \left(1+\varepsilon_n (x)\right)$. I am not sure whether you answered this already but I didn't get it. So could you give me a necessary condition on $\varepsilon$ such that the above holds? Maybe with a "proof idea"?

Comment: It's hard to say, because you need to look at what depends on what. Certainly the latter equality will depend on knowing about the approximate size of $h_n(y+1) - h_n(y)$ for values of $y$ besides the value of $x$ you're looking at. I'd say the more concrete you make your question, the clearer it will be to people.

Comment: In order to make it more concrete, I tried to post the whole example. As I have no idea about convergence, I do not know which Information might be important and which might be not. I tried to post another question in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930704/does-f-nx1-f-nx-gx-left1-varepsilon-nx-right-imply-f-nxt-f
So I will try to state the dependencies there.

Comment: I tried to again involve the example there in a simplified way. I hope this might help someone! Thank you for your help up to now. Not only you helped me pointing out what might be important in my question but also gave me some idea of what we are talking about .. :-)
I would be really grateful if you could take a look at my concrete question, as I tried to solve it for hours and I am stuck!! I do not know how to proceed now.